# Including a file via include in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, include

Basically, I'm currently in the process of developing some form of **Framework**, It's going to have a main index file that'll control the pages that are displayed, I'll then `include` files based on the URL that is rewritten using **.htaccess**, so my **.htaccess** would look something like this.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" html 
AddType "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" txt 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase / 

    # if file not exists 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # if dir not exists     
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # avoid 404s of missing assets in our script 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC] 

    # core framework url rewriting 
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

While keeping in mind that I have this line `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` I'd then use the following in my **index.php**

```
define("PAGES", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pages");

$uri = explode("/",substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1));
if((isset($uri[0])) && ($uri[0]!="")) {$page = $uri[0];} else {$page = "login";}

if(is_file(PAGES."/$page/$page.php")) {
    include(PAGES."/$page/$page.php");
} else {
    include(PAGES."/error_pages/404.php");
}
```

Would this be deemed as secure enough? or would this provide the ability for some form of exploit to be done?

Comment: This seems fine many CMS framework like WP operator on similar pattern.

Comment: Thank you for this comment, It's always best to get another developers point of view

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to use namespaces and autoloading features of PHP >= 5.3
Your solution be secure until users can't create their own files in DOCUMENT_ROOT and you should avoid possibility of including files out of DOCUMENT_ROOT.